# SqlParameter: Difference in passing SqlDbType vs without passing

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I am using SqlParameter to add parameters so that stored procedures can be executed.

I would like to know the difference between passing the SqlDbType vs without passing it. What benefits do we get if we pass the SqlDbType as well?

Answer (score 0):

Specifies SQL Server-specific data type of a field, property, for use in a SqlParameter.
This will help in performance during execution of stored procedure as there is less efforts involved in changing datatypes at runtime.
This avoids typecast and run time errors due to inappropriate data.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is called many times, having a precise definition of your parameters allows better optimization by the database engine.

[This is a very important article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx) about the effects of your data access code on performance.

Basically, if you specify correctly the type, size, precision and scale of your parameters, the Sql Optimizer could reuse your query without re-elaborating a costly query plan.

For example. Adding a string parameter with AddWithValue (a useful shrtcut) will void the optimization because the string is passed with NVarChar type and with a variable size every time you call the stored procedure.